# Mercurial keyword expansion utf-8

Tags: utf-8, mercurial

I am using mercurial for versioning my perl scripts on a win 7 system. The scripts are `utf-8` files. I activated keyword expansion, to see the commit message, ... in the files itself. This works fine, expect one little thing. If I have umlauts like `ÄÖÜäöü...` in my commit message, I see something like:

> "xFC" (= ü) or "xE4" (= ä) as replaced keywords.

The only thing I found is this, which I put in my mercurial configuration

```
[web]
encoding = utf-8
```

But this doesn't help. How can I force mercurial to replace the keywords with utf-8 encoding, or any other encoding I want?

Comment: Show : 1) your keyword definition 2) you windows codepage (of console). Hint: you **must** to recode Windows-* string into UTF8 before pasting

Comment: `[web]` section doesn't correlate with your task at all, it's just codepage of embedded server (hg serve)

Comment: 1)
    [keyword]
    **.pl =
    **.pm =
    **.bat =
    
    [keywordmaps]
    Author = {author|person}
    EMail = {author|email}
    Date = {date|isodate}
    last_log = {desc|nonempty}
    Version = {latesttag|nonempty}
    RevLocal = {rev}
    RevID = {node|short}
    Source = {root}/{file}
    Datei = {file}


2) cp-1252


3) What should i recode, my commit message? How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see *now* any way to achieve correct results, because

1. In keyword definition you|we can use only template+filters and plain-text, not HG-commands and OS-commands
2. Inserting non-UTF8 strings into UFT8-encoded file broke (in my tests, possible incorrect in style) file - file converted to ANSI, UTF8-parts become unreadable

---

## My test-case

- 1251 (Russian Windows) codepage - full 8bit
- UTF8 (with BOM) files in repo with some Russian strings in it
- Commits with Russian text in commit message (in order to mix UTF8 files and 1251 log-message)
- Your full keywordmaps (while I could use only `last_log`)

As result, I got (you can't read Russian chunks, but can compare these strings before and after)

**Source**

```
Country=RU
Name=Scartel-Yota
Site=http://www.yota.ru
Image=Scartel-Yota.bmp

City=Москва
```

**With keywords expanded** (file became **ANSI-encoded**)

```
// $last_log: Исправлено кодирование на UTF8 $

Country=RU
Name=Scartel-Yota
Site=http://www.yota.ru
Image=Scartel-Yota.bmp

City=Р СљР С•РЎРѓР С”Р Р†Р В°
```

**Сonclusion**

In order to get smooth results, you must to recode log-message into UTF8 before inserting into UTF8-target, something like

`chcp 65001 && hg log -r tip -T "{desc|nonempty}"`

but I can't (don't know, how to) use *any* HG-commands in keywordmaps (chcp+log can be shell-alias for usability and readablity, but anyway alias can't be part of keyword-definition AFAICS)

Comment: I use tortoiseHG with the Workbench GUI. Usualy i make my checkin's here.